# How to delete table created by manytomany relationship in typeorm by changing entity

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I previously add a many to many relation with my User and Project entity

User

```
import { Entity, Column, OneToMany, ManyToMany } from "typeorm";
import { BaseUuidEntity } from "../utils/entity/baseUuidEntity";
import { Project } from "./project";
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseUuidEntity {
  @Column("varchar", { nullable: false, length: 40 })
  Name!: string;

  @Column("varchar", { nullable: false, length: 40 })
  Email!: string;

  @ManyToMany((type) => Project, (Project) => Project.Id)
  Projects: Project[];
}
```

Project.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, OneToMany, ManyToMany, JoinTable } from "typeorm";
import { BaseUuidEntity } from "../utils/entity/baseUuidEntity";
import { Bug } from "./bug";
import { User } from "./user";
@Entity()
export class Project extends BaseUuidEntity {
  @Column("varchar", { nullable: false, length: 32 })
  ProjectName!: string;

  @Column({ type: "bool" })
  IsArchived: boolean;

  @Column("boolean")
  IsPrivate: boolean;

  @ManyToMany((type) => User)
  @JoinTable({
    name: "ProjectMember", // table name for the junction table of this relation
    joinColumn: {
      name: "user",
      referencedColumnName: "Id",
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: "project",
      referencedColumnName: "Id",
    },
  })
  Members: User[];

  @OneToMany((type) => Bug, (Bug) => Bug.Id)
  Bugs: Bug[];
}
```

But Now I have removed the many to many relation from both entity and created a new Entity Project member

But when I ran the migration script it didn't delete the JoinTable created by many to Many relation, how can I delete it?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. I will try to create my own migration now using the down of the migration that created that relationship. Please let me know, if you found the solution.
UPDATE: It worked pretty well.